# Margin Between X-Axis Title and X-Axis Labels in AChartEngine

Tags: java, android, achartengine

Iam using AChartEngine Stacked Bar Chart. Can i add spacing between X-Axis Title and X-Axis Labels. They are too closed to each other.

set Bottom Margin will only add spacing between X-Axis Title and Legend.

Comment: It's the second time you un-accept one of my answers. I will not answer your questions anymore.

Comment: is it wrong to accept someone's answer which gave better results? I now leave it to you if you feel that i should not accept the better answer then you can happily never answer any of my questions. I always appreciated any kind of help u have given me i guess you forgot to take that into account.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A quick patch which solved my problem, modify your X-Axis Title and prefix it with new lines, e.g

```
    renderer.setXTitle("\n\n\n Months");
```

Comment: This is not real answer , putting new line char will never be true answer, actually there is no such a method for spacing between X axes labels and Y-axes labels

Comment: @Jayesh,  I know "there is no such a method", but the fact is that developers are expecting such method,so the "Quick Patch" remains the only option for developers. The intention of the answer was not to be accepted and I would appreciate correct answer always.You should upvote the question to draw attention of AchartEngine developers effectively instead just pointing out this answer.

Answer (score 12):

Use the `setMargins()` method. You can set the margins between the chart and the margins of the screen.

```
renderer.setMargins(new int[] {30, 100, 10, 0);
```

The order of the values in the parameter array is: top, left, bottom, right. So, you will need to increase the left value.

Comment: You got it wrong buddy i want to add spacing between X-Axis Title and X-Axis Labels.

Comment: Have you tried the solution I have provided you? Try it first and then tell me if I am wrong or right.

Comment: i tried it it adds margin between screen and chart. Not between individual elements of chart like Title on X-Axis and Labels on X-Axis

Comment: If you try it you would see that the X axis label stays close to the screen margin, while the chart itself, together with the axis and axis labels move as the setMargins specifies.

Comment: The Left margin works as required for Y-Axis Title and Y-Axis Labels but i n need to do it for X-Axis

Comment: @FahadAbidJanjua hello, just saw this thread. did you manage to solve this?.. i having been looking for a solution to this and the above solution from Dan does not seem to solve the problem. Any luck with this? Thank you

Comment: @Dan followed your solution, but that is not creating the space between the X-Axis labels and X-Axis titles. anyway i can solve this? am writing date values on the x-axis on a 30 degree angle, so i need to be able to space it out a bit. Please would be grateful on how to solve this. thanks

Comment: @Dan i tried values like new int[] {10, 30, 15, 10}; and it just moves the chart but not the spacing. i don't know whether the OP stated it correctly or i want something different but what i want is.. spacing between each unit on the x-axis and their corresponding text labels(it would be a vertical spacing). if you think i should open a new thread for this, let me know.

Comment: Just use {10, 30, 50, 10} and let me know.

Comment: @Dan i tried it but it doesn't work. everything moves including the X-Axis title which seems strange. please have a look at this picture link: http://www5.picturepush.com/photo/a/11340003/img/11340003.jpg. I want the text to move down. Thank you.

Comment: The X axis labels are part of the chart, so that won't move. You can hide the labels.

Comment: @Dan Thanks for the time. At least i know now. by the way, is there a way to stop the X-Axis Title from moving when using setMargin. the Y-AxisTitle stays put but the X-Axis moves or is that part of the chart as well?

Comment: @Dan can you tell me how can i make my bar to move away from y axis line .....actually what my half of width is hidden behind the y axis line.......help...thanx in ad.

Comment: @GauravKumawat You probably have to play with renderer.setXAxisMin()

Answer (score 1):

use this method:  setXLabelsPadding